# buildToolsVersion not specified

Tags: android, build.gradle

I am getting an error "Project Refresh Failed. Cause: buildToolsVersion not specified"
Here is my app\build.gradle file

```
apply plugin:'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(':aars')
    compile project(':models')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.1.0'
}
```

Here is my project gradle file

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.3.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

Any help please?

Comment: Check the aars and models build.gradle files

Comment: Please add the `build.gradle` of your modules `aars` and `models`.

Comment: @Naila how you solved please post you answer

Comment: @GowthamanM check my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was my "JAVA_HOME" variable. I was giving path to the /bin directory folder **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172\bin**. Changing this path to **C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_172** solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

In My cause i missed this line in **app.gradle**  so check your app.gradle blow format.

> **buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"**

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"  // check this line present or not
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "edu.cmu.sphinx.pocketsphinx"
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1"
    }
}
```